# Bash : use variable in variable (nested loop)

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a makefile and I want to compile each of my vhdl files in the correct library. And there is my code :

```
    $(DEBUG)for core_lib in $(CORE_LIB_LIST); \
        do for core_lib_src_vhd in $($$core_lib.VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST); \
            do $(COMPILER_VHDL) $(CC_VHDL_OPTIONS) $(COVER_OPTIONS) -work $$core_lib $(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/$$core_lib_src_vhd; \
        done; \
    done;
```

But $($$core_lib.VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST) is unrecognized.

Comment: Shouldn't all the variable just have one $ with no brackets i.e. $core_lib.VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST. By using $() you are attempting to use the output of an executed command.

Comment: If i remove $($), I obtain "do for core_lib_src_vhd in ore_lib.VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST" and if I only remove one $ : "do for core_lib_src_vhd in " (same with 2 $)

Comment: Should for core_lib_src_vhd in $core_lib.VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST;

Comment: If I write "do for core_lib_src_vhd in $core_lib.VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST", my terminal answers me : 
    do for core_lib_src_vhd in ore_lib.VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST
I don't really understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that in `$($$core_lib.VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST)` `core_lib`  is a shell variable and you want make to expand it first, and then expand the make variable which name is `${core_lib}.VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST`. This is not how make works. You cannot expect make to expand shell variables.

Instead you should rely on make variables only. Assuming:

- make variable `CORE_LIB_LIST` is the list of libraries,
- for each library `LIB` there is a make variable `LIB.VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST` listing the source files,
- the source files are in `$(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/`,

you could try this:

```
.PHONY: compile-all-libs

# $(1): library
define COMPLIB_rule
.PHONY: compile-$(1)

compile-$(1):
    $$(DEBUG)$$(COMPILER_VHDL) $$(CC_VHDL_OPTIONS) $$(COVER_OPTIONS) -work $(1) $$(addprefix $$(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/,$$($(1).VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST))

compile-all-libs: compile-$(1)
endef

$(foreach LIB,$(CORE_LIB_LIST),$(eval $(call COMPLIB_rule,$(LIB))))
```

**Explanation**: the `define COMPLIB_rule ... endef` is just another way to define a make variable named `COMPLIB_rule`. The `$(foreach ...` construct must be put flat in the Makefile (not in a recipe). It iterates over the words in the definition of make variable `CORE_LIB_LIST`. For each word `LIB`, it replaces `$(1)` by `LIB` in the definition of `COMPLIB_rule` (it also replaces every `$$` by a single `$`) and it instantiates the result as a regular make rule. If the make variable `CORE_LIB_LIST` evaluates as `a b`, for instance, the result will be the same as:

```
.PHONY: compile-a

compile-a:
    $(DEBUG)$(COMPILER_VHDL) $(CC_VHDL_OPTIONS) $(COVER_OPTIONS) -work a $(addprefix $(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/,$(a.VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST))

compile-all-libs: compile-a

.PHONY: compile-b

compile-b:
    $(DEBUG)$(COMPILER_VHDL) $(CC_VHDL_OPTIONS) $(COVER_OPTIONS) -work b $(addprefix $(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/,$(b.VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST))

compile-all-libs: compile-b
```

So, if you type `make compile-all-libs`, make will try to build `compile-a` and `compile-b`, the two pre-requisites of `compile-all-libs`. In order to build `compile-a` it will execute the recipe:

```
$(DEBUG)$(COMPILER_VHDL) $(CC_VHDL_OPTIONS) $(COVER_OPTIONS) -work a $(addprefix $(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/,$(a.VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST))
```

which will compile in library `a` all source files listed in make variable `a.VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST` and found in directory `$(BLOCK_PATH)/cores`. Same with `compile-b`.

But of course, it would be much better if you were recompiling only what's needed (that is, source files that changed since the last time they were compiled). This can be done with empty tag files that keep track of the last time a source file was compiled:

```
.PHONY: compile-all-libs

# $(1): library
# $(2): source file basename
define COMPLIB_rule
$$(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/$(1).$(2).tag: $$(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/$(2)
    $$(DEBUG)$$(COMPILER_VHDL) $$(CC_VHDL_OPTIONS) $$(COVER_OPTIONS) -work $(1) $$< && \
    touch $$@

compile-all-libs: $$(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/$(1).$(2).tag
endef

$(foreach LIB,$(CORE_LIB_LIST),$(foreach FILE,$($(LIB).VHDL_SRC_FILES_LIST),$(eval $(call COMPLIB_rule,$(LIB),$(FILE)))))

clean:
    $(DEBUG)rm -f $(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/*.tag
```

**Explanation**: there, the `foreach-foreach-eval-call` iterates over library/source file pairs. For each `LIB-FILE` pair, it replaces `$(1)` by `LIB` and `$(2)` by `FILE` in the definition of `COMPLIB_rule` (it also replaces every `$$` by a single `$`) and it instantiates the result as a regular make rule. All this declares all `LIB.FILE.tag` files as pre-requisites of target `compile-all-libs` and declares the rule to build the tag by compiling `FILE` in `LIB` and touching the tag file. This is just like if, for each source `FILE` of library `LIB`, you added this to your Makefile:

```
$(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/LIB.FILE.tag: $(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/FILE
    $(DEBUG)$(COMPILER_VHDL) $(CC_VHDL_OPTIONS) $(COVER_OPTIONS) -work LIB $< && \
    touch $@

compile-all-libs: $(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/LIB.FILE.tag
```

Just type `make compile-all-libs` and see: make will build all tag files, that is, compile each source file in its own library and touch the tag file. As the VHDL source file is a pre-requisite of the tag file, it is only if the VHDL source file is more recent than the tag file that the recipe will be executed. This is the same as the `.o` / `.c` dependency for C programs. The only difference is that we do not use the compilation result itself (`.o`) because we do not really know what it is with Modelsim. Instead, we create a tag file, just for this purpose. Side effect: it would be exactly the same with a different VHDL compiler/simulator.

This would even give you the possibility to declare dependencies between your source files: if `$(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/foo.vhd` must be compiled in library `FOO_LIB` before `$(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/bar.vhd` can be compiled in library `BAR_LIB`, you could add:

```
$(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/BAR_LIB.bar.vhd.tag: $(BLOCK_PATH)/cores/FOO_LIB.foo.vhd.tag
```

to your Makefile. And there are also many possible improvements like, for instance, per-library goals...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the few lines i have posted are already in a target so I think I can't use compile-all-libs in target (maybe also define) ?

Comment: Can't you simply declare `compile-all-libs` as a pre-requisite of your target and get rid of this part of the recipe?

Comment: But compile-all-libs is in the define. There is no problem to call a pre-requisite which is in define ? Which value will take $(1) and $(2) ?

Comment: Where should I put the foreach line ? In a receipe ?

Comment: I edited may answer to add a short explanation about `define - endef` and `foreach-eval-call`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience, I begin to understand your solution.
Do you know how can I execute the prerequisite compile-all-libs on a condition ?

Comment: It depends on the condition. What would it look like?

Comment: There is not always core libs and files, only when Xilinx IP are used. If there is no core IP, I wouldn't like to compile this files. I have defined in my makefile a variable CORES_EN, if this variable == 1, compile-all-libs else dont.

Comment: There are several options. Instead of defining `CORES_EN` as 1 you could define it as `compile-all-libs` or nothing and add `$(CORES_EN)` as a pre-requisite of your initial target instead of `compile-all-libs`. Note that make could discover alone whether `$(BLOCK_PATH)/cores` exists or not and build `compile-all-libs` if it exists, else not. But this deserves another question. More likely, it has already been asked and answered on SO.